# How can I create an object in jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I have created an object in `jquery`

```
var obj= {'First': 'yellow','Second': 'red'};
```

I want to post this object to a vb function which has an objcolor which has primary and tint as properties. The function has two other parameters; sport and car.  my post is

```
$.post('URL.action('ColorReal'),{'sport': 'bowling', 'car': 'olds', 'objcolor': 'obj'});
```

I set a breakpoints after the function in vb.net controller to see if parameters of function are populated sport as bowling and car has old but the objcolor has nothing.  I have tried `JSON.stringify(objcolor)` in the post and still nothing is passed. How should the object setting in the post be constructed?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `obj` - i.e. `.... 'objcolor': obj})` If its not binding. post your controller method and model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like

```js
var ob = {
  'sport': 'bowling',
  'car': 'olds',
  'objcolor': [{
    'First': 'yellow',
    'Second': 'red'
  }]
}

$.post('URL.action("ColorReal")', ob);
```

Comment: Did this exactly as given and still object is not passing.  Function in controller looks something like this Function ColorReal(sport as sports, car as cars, objcolor as colors).  model gives propertys of objcolor as first{get:set} and second{get:set}

Comment: how this come objcolor as colors ? i think your object is modifying .